# Import in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I'm working on my first game and I have a little over 20 classes.

Although it's manageable as it is, I would like to be able to arrange them a bit. It's a "space game", where I have multiple ship types, which each have their own class, which inherits the abstract "ship" class. I would like to put them in a single "Ships" package (and still be able to use them).

So how can this be achieved with Eclipse? I know how to create a package folder in a project, but I don't know how to import them when I need them in a different package of the project.

I have tried searching for an answer but all the examples and answers I've found go way over my simple needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's so easy question. you don't need to import them handy , just when you use your class in other class , for example `Ship ship = new Ship();` . if you use auto complete for Ship with ctrl+space eclipse import them automatic, but if you write it and don't use auto complete use ctrl+shift+O to import the class. so easy.

Comment: If I just drag it to another package in Eclipses file tree(inside Eclipse) it'll give me an error: The "Insert class here" cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: you mean drag a class from a package to another... maybe that class is open or do something on it. anyway just close that class and copy it to that package or in that class in first line (package com....) change it to destination package, for example : `package com.Pro` to `package com.bip`, then press ctrl+1 on it and choose move to destination package. but use copy is easier.

Comment: ahaa.. I am using the default package for the rest of the files.. Could that be it? because it seemed to work when I moved a class to anther non default package...

Comment: i don't know, like what? so change that default package name like the others.

Comment: Yeah. I think I've figured it out... now it's only crying about references to another packages variables, but that is something I can reasonably easily fix. Thanks a lot! My issue has been solved!

Comment: ok. good. just don't forget if my reply is your answer, accept it.

Comment: ok, this was my first question ever... still figuring out to use this site... ;D but thanks again!